# Macruby on OS X Mavericks

Tags: ruby, macruby

I'm running OS X Mavericks and installed MacRuby last week in order to make a simple app in it. Anything I try to run in Xcode (even Hello World app or a downloaded example), I always get "Build Failed" and really similar errors to this:

[image]

I found in some forums that th Garbage Collection is really deprecated etc. but I could't find any solution. Therefore I would be very glad if someone has a solution for this.

And no, I can't just work in Objective-C since it's far too complicated for me and apps I'd make :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MacRuby isn't currently compatible with 10.9, not just because of the garbage collector, but due to changes in the Objective-C runtime, LLVM, and Xcode. There is a thread (titled "Mavericks and Macruby") going on [right now on the macruby-devel mailing list](https://lists.macosforge.org/pipermail/macruby-devel/2013-November/thread.html) about these issues. [Joshua Ballanco's message](https://lists.macosforge.org/pipermail/macruby-devel/2013-November/009150.html) especially sheds a lot of light on what it would take to keep MacRuby going.

You can still use the garbage collector by setting `GCC_ENABLE_OBJC_GC = supported` in Xcode; but as I said, it won't make MacRuby actually usable (yet).

Comment: thanks for an explanation.. too bad that I decided to learn macruby when it is not usable anymore :D

Comment: Yeah... it really is a shame (unless someone is able to fix it!)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest people interested in cocoa in ruby help out refining the
cocoa gem instead of hoping for any progress on macruby which is
abandoned by its creators for commercial interests. The cocoa gem
is quite useful already, but need to mature a bit in some cases.

```
https://github.com/patrickhno/cocoa
```

DISCLAIMER: Yes I am the author.